# Mutexes and thread priorities with regards to scheduling on POSIX systems

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, mutex, thread-priority

In POSIX systems (linux etc), when multiple threads lock a common mutex - is it the locking order that is ***always*** observed, or does thread priority bias threads of higher priority when it comes scheduling the next thread in the critical section?

Does the standard mention anything about the behavior? because as far as I can see it only seems to mention the required interface.

Please note, I'm looking of guidance on any POSIX conformant system (not just linux), so feel free to suggest the behavior of other OSes (QNX, Minix etc..)

Comment: the syscall used is called futex(2) (on linux at least)

Comment: As far as i know, whenever we are trying to lock a mutex or a semaphore, and are unsucesfull, these processes are sent into a queue. Every semaphore/mutex has a queue. Once there is an increment on a semaphore variable, the queue is checked and a new process in invoked based on FIFO Algorithm(Source Galvin). So answer should ideally be locking order but am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 4):

When multiple threads are **waiting** to lock the same mutex, when the mutex becomes available, the highest priority thread will be unblocked first.  If multiple threads have the same priority, which thread is unblocked will depend on the scheduling algorithm used, e.g. using a FIFO policy, the thread that has been waiting that the longest will be awakened first.

Thread priorities and synchronisation is quite a thorny area and you need to be very careful you don't end up with priority inversion and cause deadlock.

Chapter 5.5 of Butenhof's *Programming with POSIX Threads* deals with realtime scheduling.

Comment: So what you're saying is that it is entirely based on the FIFO ordering and not related to priority?

Comment: No, I'm saying the thread priority is the primary factor, and if multiple threads have the same priority, the scheduling algorithm determines which thread to awaken.